# Programming with dplyr: indirectly control by which variables to group by

Tags: r, dplyr, evaluation

I want to write a simple function `f(grouping)` that summarises the data below:

```
d0 <- data.frame(
  V1 = rep(1:5, times = 2),
  V2 = rep(2:6, times = 2),
  V3 = rep(11:15, times = 2),
  V4 = rep(12:16, times = 2),
  X = 1:10
)
```

I want the user to be able to pick between two kinds of groupings: either by `V1` or by `V2`, in that the user either writes `f(grouping = V1)` or `f(grouping = V2)`. However, I want it to be such that if `grouping = V1`, it groups by `V1` and `V3`. And if `grouping = V2`, then it groups by `V2` and `V4`. Note that, since `V3` and `V4` originally have unintuitive names, they should not be used as arguments on the function call.

`f(V1)` should yield:

```
 # A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   V1 [5]
     V1    V3     X
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1    11     7
2     2    12     9
3     3    13    11
4     4    14    13
5     5    15    15
```

And `f(V2)`:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   V2 [5]
     V2    V4     X
  <int> <int> <int>
1     2    12     7
2     3    13     9
3     4    14    11
4     5    15    13
5     6    16    15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a condition with `if/else` to concatenate 'V3' or 'V4' based on the value of the input `grouping`.  Inside the function, convert the unquoted grouping value to symbol (`ensym`), and then to string (`as_string`), then use `if/else` to concatenate the groups, pass the updated the groups ('grp') within `across` and `summarise` the 'X'

```
f1 <- function(data, grouping) {
        grp <- rlang::as_string(ensym(grouping))
        grp <- c(grp, if(grp == 'V1') 'V3' else 'V4')

        data %>%
            group_by(across(all_of(grp))) %>%
            summarise(X = sum(X), .groups = 'drop')

}

f1(d0, V1)
f1(d0, V2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you adapt your answer for a case with something like ```f(d0, grouping = c(V1,V2)```. For some reason, I get an error: ```Only strings can be converted to symbols```.

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito If you are passing as a vector.  Then,  it is better to pass as strings.  `c("V1", "V2")` and inside the function, you don't need the `grp <- rlang::as_string(ensym(grouping))`, instead can be `grp <- c(grp, if('V1' %in% grouping) 'V3 else 'V4')`

Comment: But does ```group_by``` work with strings? I ask because there is an extra argument on the function that also selects grouping variables, but with no need to indirectly add ones connected to it. So that it would be good to have some symmetry

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito yes, if you check my code, it is `group_by(across(all_of(grp))` i.e. the strings can be passed in `across`

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito Previously, there used to `group_by_at` and pass `vars(grp)` inside, now it is `across` with `all_of` or `any_of` (in case some grouping variables are not present in the data)